# Taxonomy order exception for specific term

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, terms

I want to make an exception for my custom taxonomy order. Sometimes you need to put "Other" option as last option but when calling taxonomies with "orderby=name", sadly "Other" term is not listing as last option. Is there any proper way for this exception?

Comment: Is this about front or backend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the example of `get_terms` in the Codex:

```
$terms = get_terms("my_taxonomy");
 $count = count($terms);
 if ( $count > 0 ){
     echo "<ul>";
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";

     }
     echo "</ul>";
 }
```

Lets say there was an 'other' term in `my_taxonomy`. To place it at the end as you requested, we would check each term if it matched, and put it aside for safekeeping. Then, when the loop is finished, we would check if it was found and display it at the end.

e.g.

```
 $terms = get_terms("my_taxonomy");
 $count = count($terms);
 if ( $count > 0 ){
     echo "<ul>";
     $other_term = null;
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       if($term->name == 'other'){
           $other_term = $term;
       } else {
           echo "<li>" . $term->name . "</li>";
       }
     }
     if($other_term != null){
       echo "<li>" . $other_term->name . "</li>";
     }
     echo "</ul>";
 }
```

Think of it as a queue, first in first out, only when the person called 'other' arrives at the window for processing, a guard grabs him and pulls him aside. When the queue is empty and everyone has been processed, the guard puts the 'other' person back in the queue at the end.